# Using a variable outside of an lambda expression block in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, scope

So, I have a program that loads an image with a FileChooser. I use a lambda expression to define this loading action so the function `LoadImage()` returns the chosen image inside the event block but I can't use it outside this block.

Can someone help me?

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Main extends Application{

    Stage window;
    BorderPane layout;
    ImageView imageView;
    Image currentImage;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Image Viewer v.1.0");

        //MENU
        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("_File");
        MenuItem openFile = new MenuItem("Open file...");
        openFile.setOnAction(e -> currentImage = LoadImage());

        fileMenu.getItems().add(openFile);

        //Main menu bar
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu);

        imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(currentImage); //here the currentImage is null

        layout = new BorderPane();
        layout.setTop(menuBar);
        layout.setCenter(imageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 900, 600);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

    }


    public Image LoadImage()
    {
            final Image image;
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

            //Set extension filter
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.JPG)", "*.JPG");
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterjpg = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("jpg files (*.jpg)", "*.jpg");
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.PNG)", "*.PNG");
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterpng = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterjpg, extFilterPNG, extFilterpng);

            //Show open file dialog
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);       

            return new Image(file.toURI().toString());
    }

} // end of Main class
```

So forth, nothing is displayed in the ImageView. 
How can I use the value returned by the `LoadImage()` method?

Comment: You're doing `setImage(currentImage)` too soon - it will be changed when the OpenFile menu is selected and LoadImage returns. Do the `setImage` in the event block to update it when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `currentImage` is indeed changed, but when you set the value of `imageView`'s `image` property, it is not yet set. You have to change the property of your `ImageView`, not the variable (which you use only before setting the image).

Try changing your lambda to:

```
openFile.setOnAction(e -> imageView.setImage(LoadImage()) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
What if I need to make some operations over the received image from the LoadImage() function, and I want to do this outside the event block ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Presumably these actions should happen every time the menu option is selected, so how can they be performed outside the event handler? If it's only a matter of style that bothers you, you don't have to use a lambda.